# Iterate through the MultiSelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have a model like this:

```
public class ArticleWriter_ViewModel
{
    public int MagId { get; set; }
    public string MagNo { get; set; }
    public string TitleIds { get; set; }
    public MultiSelectList Articles { get; set; }
    public int[] SelectedArticles { get; set; }
}
```

i fill the Articles like this:

```
    ArticleWriter_ViewModel viewModel = new ArticleWriter_ViewModel();
        Func<IQueryable<NumberTitle>, IOrderedQueryable<NumberTitle>> orderByFunc = null;
        Expression<Func<NumberTitle, bool>> filterExpr = null;
        if (id > 0)
        {
            filterExpr = p => p.MagazineId.Equals(id);
        }
        var wholeTitles = unitOfWork.NumberTitleRepository.Get(filterExpr, orderByFunc, "Magazine,Title").ToList();
```

then pass it to view. in a few views i show Article in DropDownListFor, but in others want to show it in DisplayFor.how can i iterate through the Articles to show in DisplayFor?

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx  maybe you need a display template

Comment: would you please give me some more information about it?

Comment: if you want use Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.PropertyName),the property is a complex type,add a attribute [UIHit] and create a display template,just see the hanselman's blog

Answer (score 0):

Create a display template in your project's `Views\DisplayTemplates` directory (create the folder if necessary) called ArticleWriter_ViewModel.cshtml like this (Razor syntax):

```
@model ArticleWriter_ViewModel
@foreach (NumberTitle article in Model) 
{
  @Html.DisplayFor(article => article.Title) 
}
```

You can change the property referenced in the DisplayFor expression and/or add an expression to filter the list of articles as required.

If you want to give the display template a different name, use the UIHint annotation on the model name to assign the template name:

```
[UIHint("MyTemplate")]
public class ArticleWriter_ViewModel
{...}
```